# Cannot recognize inputString as symbol?

Tags: java

In the following lines of code, an error shows up saying that it cannot recognize inputString as a symbol in both instances of it in the code.

```
error: cannot find symbol 

inputString

^
```

The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.Math;
import type.lib.*;

public class Check06B

{
    public static final String CODE_STRING = "||::::::||::||::|::|:|:|::||::|:::||::|:|:|::";
    public static final String CODE_NUMBERS = "0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9";
    public static final int CODE_LENGTH = 5;
    public static final int ERROR_DIVISOR = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintStream print = new PrintStream(System.out);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        print.println("Enter a string of digits: ");
        String x = input.nextLine();

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("|");

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++)
        {
            String digit = inputString.substring(i, i + 1);
            sum += Integer.parseInt(digit);
            result.append(CODE_STRING.substring(CODE_NUMBERS.indexOf(digit),CODE_NUMBERS.indexOf(digit) + CODE_LENGTH));
        }

        int crc= (ERROR_DIVISOR - (sum % ERROR_DIVISOR)) % ERROR_DIVISOR;
        result.append(CODE_STRING.substring(CODE_NUMBERS.indexOf("" + crc),CODE_NUMBERS.indexOf("" + crc) + CODE_LENGTH));
        result.append("|");

        print.println("POSTNET Code: " + result.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You never declare any `inputString` variable.

Perhaps you meant to use this variable instead :

```
String x = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake -

```
String x = input.nextLine();
```

should be

```
String inputString = input.nextLine();
```